# Get all opened desktop applications using WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a Visual Tree Explorer application (like Snoop, Mole) which should automatically identify all desktop applications and detect whether it is a WPF app. or not. I am tring to do this in WPF. Is there any way to get all WPF opened applications. Any special API, or native functions in system dlls, etc.

Regards,

Jawahar

Answer (score 3):

I think you can iterate through the list of all processes and for those processes who have a window, check if the window class name starts with HwndWrapper (I've noticed the WPF windows have a class name like this: HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;2e60e21a-8752-4daf-820b-aed289668930])

The code should be something like this:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process p in procs)
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(257);
        RealGetWindowClass(p.MainWindowHandle, sb, 256);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        if(sb.ToString().StartsWith("HwndWrapper"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WPF window");
        }
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint RealGetWindowClass(IntPtr hwnd, [Out] StringBuilder pszType, uint cchType);
```

with maybe some adjustments depending on your case. When dealing with such a window, one should assume it's a WPF window not take it for a certainty, so error checking must be extensive.

Comment: Whoa, careful with expecting things you've "noticed" to be stable and consistent across all configurations and future versions!! Unless you've seen this *documented* somewhere, I strongly caution you against using it with any expectations. Not to mention there may very well be *other* processes running on a system with the class name "HwndWrapper".

Comment: And that is the purpose of the last sentence from my answer.